# How to use jquery to add/subtract values in adjacent <td></td> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

A bit of a jQuery newb here but I recently have a project where I'd like to be able to subtract the values betweem adjacent table td elements within the same  series.

Example:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td colspan='3'>Year 2008</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quarter 1</td><td>Quarter 2</td><td>Change Q1-Q2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Quarter 1 Val</td><td>Quarter 2 Val</td><td>Quarter 2 - Quarter 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id='y1q1'>2</td><td id='y1q2'>6</td><td id='dy1q1q2'>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

So the idea is to populate element id='d1y1q2' with (elemid: y1q2.value - elemid: y1q1.value).

I know this should be handled at the SQL level, but out dataset is massive and the nature of the database would not well handle these calculations within queries.

Any help is much appreciated! Could the jquery DataTables plugin handle this sort of thing?

Comment: If the data cells are populated by a database, I don't see why it would be difficult to populate one more cell with the difference.

Comment: @tskuzzy I would appreciate that +1 Back: As I mentioned in the post: Our database query for this is cost prohibitive to the solution at about 600 lines with about 8 joins on tables that several highly paid mysql consultants have been unable to appropriately partition or index. Pagination is not an option.

Comment: @F. Calderan, yes the ids will be dynamically generated. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @cerd: I did not downvote your question. ._."

Comment: @tskuzzy - Apologies my friend. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @maerics To be completely honest I have not tried much. I have been working with jquery for about 2 weeks now and the project is 2 days old. SQL queries given the nature of the db structure/indexing scheme will entail runtimes of something like 20 minutes to populate. So I am looking for suggestions on using jQuery, which again I am still learning by the day as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sub = parseInt($('#y1q2').text(), 10) - parseInt($('#y1q1').text(), 10);
$('#dy1q1q2').text(sub);
```

If you're `id`s are dynamic then:

```
var lastTR = $('table tr:last'),
    tdSecond = parseInt( $('td',lastTR).eq(1).text(), 10 ),
    tdFirst = parseInt( $('td', lastTR).eq(0).text(), 10 ),
    sub = tdSecond - tdFirst;

$('td:last', lastTR).text(sub);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/196/)**

If your value can be Float also then you can use `.parseFloat()`

Comment: @cred If you table structure remain same like above then I think my second code should work just fine

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
var y1q1Val = parseFloat($('#y1q1').text());
var y1q2Val = parseFloat($('#y1q2').text());
var newVal = y1q2Val - y1q1Val;

$('#dy1q1q2').text(newVal);
```

Of course you could minimize this as you see fit...

Comment: Again a newb, these IDs will be dynamically filled. I assume your solution will be the right one but any advice on avoiding a massively bloated jquery script given I have 4500 rows each with Annual and quarterly data 2004-2012 (with the delta Qy-Qx) vals for ea. year. Perhaps a for loop?

Comment: Yes, a for loop should work. I'm not sure how well it will perform but that's something you'd have to test I suppose. It looks like thecodeparadox above has a working solution for you though.


You could loop through the id's with a for loop i.e.
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        $('#dy1q'+i+'q'+i+1).text(...)
    }


But that's not very pretty, thecodeparadox seems to have a much more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById('y1q2').innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById('y1q1').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('d1y1q2').innerHTML = a+b;
```

assuming you have only integers in those columns